# Align Text View to top when having a large title navigarion bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a View Controller inside a Navigation Controller. My View Controller only has a Text View which takes up the whole screen.

I've also set the prefersLargeTitles to true in the View Controller:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

What I'd like to do is align the Text View to the top. I've tried placing it at the top and setting the top auto-layout to 0, but then the large title is not appearing. The way I managed it to appear, is not aligning it to the top, but a little bit lower:

[image]

But then it's not correctly displayed. You can see a small gap between the title and the text:

[image]
[image]

What's the right way to do it then?

Comment: You said you aligned the text view to the "top". Can you be more specific on what the text view is constrained to? (safe area, superview, etc)

Comment: Sorry. I meant that I aligned it with the safe area.

Comment: I think I was able to replicate your issue. Just to clarify: 1) When the top spacing is 0 and you scroll up to the top does the large title appear? 2) When the top spacing is larger, does the large title animate slightly when the view controller first appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just solved my own question by aligning the Text View top to the top (**not** the safe area top). Now it's working just how I wanted to.

(Thanks @nathan :) )